# How to check spelling and grammar in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spell-checking

How can I delete all rows containing a spelling or grammar error in a Google sheet? I'd prefer doing this through Google Apps Script.

What I've considered:

- Using the spell checker from the Tools menu is too slow since I have
  a few tens of thousands of rows.
- I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484751/apps-script-vs-chrome-extension-writing-an-alternative-spellchecker-to-google-d) stackoverflow post, but my situation differs in
  that I do not need any popup bubbles, don't have a backend to provide
  the spell checking, and would very strongly prefer this be in Google
  Apps Script since I already have the rest of my project in Google
  Apps Script.
- [Creating a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484751/apps-script-vs-chrome-extension-writing-an-alternative-spellchecker-to-google-d). Problem: I don't have the constraint of needing to create popup bubbles, don't have the benefit of a spellchecking server, and would strongly prefer a solution that used Google App Script or Google Sheets functionality.
- [Checking whether the language is English](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125343/spell-check-with-formula-or-apps-script). Problem: many sentences with spelling and grammar errors still pass as english
- [typo.js](https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js). Problem: it does not seem to check
  grammar.
- [javascriptspellcheck](https://www.javascriptspellcheck.com). Problem: my project is
  commercial, the license fee of $300 isn't worth it for me, and judging by the copyright, this hasn't been maintained since 2017.

Comment: Google apps script doesn't provide any classes to access the spell checker. Closest you can come is the [`LanguageApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language) and  you might be able to access [`detectLanguage`](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects/detectLanguage), which may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/spell-check/

Comment: @SourabhChoraria I hadn't tried that, thanks for the suggestion! This project has been put on the backburner, but I'll try Bing Spell Check when I pick it back up.

Comment: Check out [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439204/google-spell-checker-api) It seems possible, using XmlService, and UrlFetchApp